# Adding an if/else statement to an existing script

Tags: php

How I can include a check if `$number` is `1` to update the `INFO` table with `Number` column `199` as default, but if `$number` is `2` to UPDATE the `INFO` table with `Number` `221` instead of `199` ?

**Basically I need to add only the check and update with 199 or 221, so please let me know how I can do this? Thanks!**

```
    $number_rows = $db->doQuery('SELECT Num FROM Char WHERE ? IN(CharNum1, CharNum2, CharNum3)', $char);
    $row = $db->doRead();
    $number = intval($row['Num']);
    if ($number_rows == -1)
    {
        $db->GetError(__file__, __line__);
        $this->doError(Template::GetLangVar('DBERROR'));
        return;
    }
    else if ($number_rows == 0)
    {
        $this->content = Template::Load('error', array('error_message' => Template::GetLangVar('No_Rows')));
        return;
    }
    $dt = $db->doQuery('SELECT TOP 1 LAINO, DT FROM LOGG WHERE Char = ? ORDER BY DT DESC', $char);
    $row = $db->doRead();
    if ((intval($row['DT']) + 600) <= time() || !$dt)
    {
        $this->database[GAB]->doQuery('INSERT INTO Laeima (UserID) VALUES (?)', $char;
        $this->database[GAB]->doQuery('INSERT INTO Smotka (Pofka,Motka,Rebka) VALUES (?,?,?)', $_SESSION['Acc'], $char, time());
        sleep(6);
        $this->database[GAB]->doQuery('UPDATE INFO SET Number = ? WHERE User = ?', $numcode, $char);
        $this->content = Template::Load('error', array('error_message' => Template::GetLangVar('Success')));
    }
    else
    {
        $this->content = Template::Load('error', array('error_message' => Template::GetLangVar('FAIL')));
    }
```

I use MSSQL Server 2005, just to mention it :)

Comment: The script works as it is but I need to add the check only so it will update INFO table and Number column according to it. If `$number` is 1 or If its 2 .. Update the Number column on INFO table as 199 or 221 ..... Will really appreciate a help on this one.

Comment: I'm not clear where you are stuck - you seem to have a good understanding of `if()` and `UPDATE ... WHERE` already, and those seem to be all that's needed for your change.

Comment: Exactly, that's what I need but I am stuck because .. can I use if once again in this if block with the update and how to separate if its `$number` 1 or 2 to update differently the INFO table ? As you said that's all I need but as you can see I am stuck :)

Comment: Please point me out how to it. I will appreciate it a lot;.

Comment: You can use as many `if` statements as you want. This is really an incredibly simple programming task, and I'm struggling to think what general answer could be given other than writing the code for you, and leaving you no better off for the next change. Since this site is about spreading knowledge, not a code-writing service, I'm reluctant to do that.

Comment: I totally understand just don't understand how I can separate the UPDATE INFO table query to update with 199 or 221 as Number column and how if I include IF in this block of if/else it will be recognized correctly and shouldn't it mess up the if check for time? Sorry about asking this question but if I were not stuck, I will do it without asking. Still thanks a lot for your time to answer me.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, the piece of information you seem to be missing is that you can nest `if` statements as deeply as you like:

```
// ... some code ...
if ( $some_condition ) {
    // ... some conditional code ...
    if ( $some_other_condition ) {
        // ... some code to run only when both conditions are true ...
    } else {
        // ... some code to run when one condition is true but the other false ...
    }
    // ... some more code ...
} else {
    // ... what to do if the outer condition is false ...
}
// ... etc ...
```

So in your case, the simplest way to achieve it is to take this line...

```
$this->database[GAB]->doQuery('UPDATE INFO SET Number = 199 WHERE User = ?', $char);
```

...and put it into an appropriate `if`, with a different version of the same line in the `else`.

Or, more elegantly, you could define a variable for the "Number", defined using an `if ... else` block, and use that in place of the hard-coded 199 in the query.

Note that I've deliberately avoided giving the final code here, because I think you're more likely to understand what to do in future if you're not tempted to just copy and paste my version without understanding it.

Comment: Indeed I definitely can do this however it's breaking my structure of updating because if I get out the UPDATE query from the current structure, the 3rd party app that grabs data from it may not like it since it depends on others and in somewhat exact time hence the sleep function .... That's what I can see. Still I will try. Also, last question if possible: what's the best way to set a variable for example: $numcode and assign 199 or 221 depends on Num so I can use it like that in the query? Thanks a lot for trying to help me really!

Comment: The update will still run in the exact same sequence within the program - you're not moving it anywhere, just adding extra logic above it. If you really mean clock time, and your application faces race conditions to the point where evaluating an `if` condition might delay it by too much, you're going to have **much** bigger problems, because it will sometimes just happen to take that much longer anyway if the CPU is busy with something else.

Comment: Yeah, I'll appreciate if you can update your post with example how to define the variable? Just example of it. That will be the best. Thanks once again, I will accept the answer. It's much appreciated.

Comment: As for "what's the best way to set a variable", I'm really not sure what to say. `if ( $x ) { $y = 'foo'; } else { $y = 'bar'; }` is about the most basic code you can write. This may sound harsh, but if you can't write that for yourself, you might want to look up a beginner's programming tutorial before going any further.

Comment: Not harsh at all. I am still new to php and also doing tests for a whole day. (5:00 AM atm :)), I updated my main post, please lastly review it up. Thanks man .. Wait

Comment: I believe we couldn't understand mostly. Thanks a lot. However I am really new to php and still doing tests. I don't get it how this will work to set 199 or 221 out of 1 or 2 if returned for $number. Is this correct:? `if ( $x == 1) {
 $y = '199';
}
else
{
 $y = '221';
}`